# HIve - escape slash and double quote at once

Tags: csv, hive, escaping, bigdata

I have a CSV file which as one column with JSON elements.

#### CSV file in table format

[image]

#### Actual raw CSV file looks like this.

```
"1","user@domain.com","cus_placement=HFHWC7394w&status=OK{\
\"user_id": \"bhuvi\"\,\
\"phone": \"9999999999\"\,\
\"gat_id\": 18\
}"
```

I tried to create an external table on top of it with the below `table properties`

```sql
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "separatorChar" = ",",
   "quoteChar"     = "\"",
   "escapeChar" = "\\" 
)
LOCATION 'file.csv'
```

But the automatically truncated from `user_id` and rest of the values are coming from next column.

### What would be the right escape char for this?

Comment: Your data has new line char, as per your raw csv 5 rows are there and first row ends status=OK{\\n .  So  from "user_id " it is considered as 2nd row.

Comment: Yes, I tried to escape with `"escapeChar" = "\\n"`, but still its not working.

Comment: what should be the line separator in this case? \n or some thing else?

Comment: Yes that is also `\n`